# Is wolfram mathematica's semicolon(;) an expression?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Everything is an expression in wolfram, what about the semicolon `;`?

```
FullFrom[a=3;Plot] (*is `;` inside an expression? *)
```

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. `a;b` is equivalent to `CompoundExpression[a, b]`.

See [the relevant documentation](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) for more info.